# Running Win32 program from Bash for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash, android, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got the latest update from Windows that adds bash, and I was trying to script the execution of an Android emulator through this; however the Path variables of Windows are not taken into account for bash.

Plus I tried executing adb manually and I got:

```
andtest@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Android/sdk/platform-tools$ exec ./adb.exe
bash: /mnt/c/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Is there something I'm missing here? I want to use this Windows computer as a test server for Android.

Comment: Can you not just use an absolute bath to call `exec`, or create an alias?

Comment: Did you see this posting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path

Comment: I may be really wrong, but you can't execute .exe files in bash - even in windows

Comment: @adampski I get an "exec format error" when I run exec ./adb.exe

Comment: Try it without the .exe extension.

Comment: @RandySchuman same thing, also with JAVA_HOME i get this: ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/, I tried with quotes, also with "Program\ Files" but to no avail :(

Comment: Upgrade to win10 build 14955 and reinstall WSL (e.g. lxrun /install).  You will get Ubuntu 16.04 and running win binaries with Just Work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Microsoft didn't *initially* make it possible to run Windows Apps.

As of Insider Preview build 14951, announced 19 October 2016, you can run native Windows programs from Bash under Ubuntu under Windows (WSL)

> Windows binaries can now be invoked directly from the WSL command line. This gives users the ability to interact with their Windows environment and system in a way that has not been possible. As a quick example, it is now possible for users to run the following commands:
>
> `$ export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32
>   $ notepad.exe
>   $ ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2
>   $ ls -la | findstr.exe foo.txt
>   $ cmd.exe /c dir`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14951

The announcement said

> Windows Subsystem for Linux: Today we are happy to announce two large updates to WSL!
>
> - Official Ubuntu 16.04 support. Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) is installed for all new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows instances starting in build 14951.  This replaces Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).  **Existing user instances will not be upgraded automatically**.  Users on the Windows Insider program can upgrade manually from 14.04 to 16.04 using the do-release-upgrade command.
> - Windows / WSL interoperability. **Users can now launch Windows binaries directly from a WSL command prompt.  This is the number one request from our users on the WSL User Voice page.**

(my emphasis)

---

### Cause of error

The message

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

This means Bash is convinced that adb.exe is the wrong type of file for execution.

To find out why, try using:

```
file /mnt/c/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
```

For example:

```
$ pwd
/mnt/c/Windows/System32
$ ./notepad.exe
bash: ./notepad.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
$ file notepad.exe
notepad.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

---

### Windows Susbsystem for Linux

Note that Microsoft's [initial objectives for WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/faq) were

> Using Bash, you can run command-line Linux tools and apps.

Note that does not include

- graphical (X11) Linux tools and apps.
- Windows tools and apps.

---

### 32-bit binaries

I believe Microsoft's Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) currently only supports 64-bit ELF binaries, not 32-bit ELF binaries.

---

### Windows binaries

Also, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38920710/477035) it seems WSL *at time of writing this answer* did not support running Windows executables from within Bash.

This is confirmed by [HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/)

> Unfortunately, there’s no way to actually launch a Windows program or run a Windows command from within a Bash script or the Bash shell. However, you can incorporate Bash commands into a Batch script or PowerShell script

---

### Why not :-(

If you look at how Microsoft did this you can see that `Bash.exe` is a native Windows console-mode app that, I believe, basically acts as a very thin front end that communicates with an **unmodified** `/bin/bash` which does all the actual interpretation and execution of commands.

> WSL ... is primarily comprised of:
>
> - User mode session manager service that handles the Linux instance life cycle
> - Pico provider drivers (lxss.sys, lxcore.sys) that emulate a Linux kernel by translating Linux syscalls
> - Pico processes that host the **unmodified** user mode Linux (e.g. **/bin/bash**)
>
> [image]
>   <sup>*- [WSL Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)*</sup>

Since an unmodified /bin/bash does not expect to be able to run programs that are not native Linux ["ELF"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binaries, it objects to Windows ["PE"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) binaries.

I certainly don't want to run down the rabbit hole of running WINE under WSL. I suggest you avoid this idea too.

---

### Possible solution

See [project cbwin](https://github.com/xilun/cbwin)

> Launch Windows programs from "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (WSL)
>
> main features:
>
> - Win32 command line tools in the console, invoked from WSL
> - Win32 command line tools with redirections to WSL (stdin/stdout/stderr to or from pipe/file)
> - suspend/resume propagation (Ctrl-Z suspends the Win32 processes, fg resumes them)
> - exit codes propagation
> - launch "detached" GUI Windows programs (uses start of cmd)

Comment: Thanks, this also explains why the JAVA_HOME is not valid: all Java binaries are for Windows.

Comment: You could use `apt-get install default-jre default-jdk` and then you'd be able to use bash to compile .java to byte-code and run it. You should, in principle, be able to run java applications you've compiled under Windows and vice versa.

Comment: This is no longer valid.  With the latest preview build of windows 10, WSL can execute windows binaries just fine.